# View bounds not updating after screen rotation using SwiftUI in iOS 16

Tags: swiftui, rotation, ios16

It appears Apple broke the following hack in iOS 16:

`UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")`

With the following console output:

`[Orientation] BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: Setting UIDevice.orientation is not supported. Please use UIWindowScene.requestGeometryUpdate(_:)`

Based on some research, I'm using `requestGeometryUpdate`:

```
    func toggleFullScreen() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            if fullScreen.wrappedValue {
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene
                    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
                    windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .portrait)) { error in print(error) }
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
                    fullScreen.wrappedValue = false
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
                    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                    fullScreen.wrappedValue = false
                }
            } else {
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene
                    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
                    windowScene?.requestGeometryUpdate(.iOS(interfaceOrientations: .landscapeRight)) { error in print(error) }
                    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.setNeedsUpdateOfSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
                    fullScreen.wrappedValue = true
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                    AppDelegate.orientationLock = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
                    UIDevice.current.setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
                    fullScreen.wrappedValue = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The rotation now works – however, my view is not actually taking account of the appropriate frame on rotation. In landscape, the view has black bars above and below – it seems the view doesn't quite get the new screen bounds somehow. Is anybody facing the same issue?